# I want to save the input select option in the database table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I want to save the input select option in the database table using php. I want to save it in a table with existing attributes
I know how to add it when using alone table for it but I want to add it in existing table with few other attributes

ps first question bear me

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['signup'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $department = $_POST['deptlist'];

    echo $name;

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'filetracking');    

    if($connection) {
        echo "We are connected";
    } else {
        die("Database connection failed");
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO faculty(name,email,contactno,password,office) ";
    $query .= "VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$password', '$department')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$result) {
        die('Query FAILED' . mysqli_error($connection));
    } else {
        echo "Record Create"; 
    }
}

?>

<form method="post" action="signup.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="Name" class="inputmd textinput form-control required" placeholder="Full Name" style="margin-bottom: 10px" required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="Email" class="inputmd textinput form-control required" placeholder="Email" style="margin-bottom: 10px" required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone" class="control-label">Phone</label>
        <input type="number" name="phone" id="Phone" class="inputmd textinput form-control required" placeholder="Phone No" style="margin-bottom: 10px" required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="Password" class="inputmd textinput form-control" placeholder="Password" style="margin-bottom: 10px" required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">                        
        <label for="deptlist" class="control-label">Department</label>
        <select name="deptlist" form="deptform" class="inputmd form-control" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
            <option value="DCSE">Department of Computer Systems Engineering</option>
            <option value="DME">Department of Mechanical Engineering</option>
            <option value="DEE">Department of Electrical Engineering</option>
            <option value="DCS">Department of Computer Science</option>
        </select>

    <div class="form-group">                    
        <input type="submit" name="signup" id="Singup" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-info col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: And what exactly have you tried?

Comment: have a look ? to the picture .. will you ?

Comment: *"have a look ? to the picture .. will you ?"* - Post your code in a format that needs to be manipulated. Plus, the HTML too. You came asking for help, then you need to help us too.

Comment: you're also using the same opening conditionals twice.

Comment: Hash the passwords, parameterize the query, indent your code (just so it is readable).

Comment: I don't see `<form></form>` tags and with a method or any other inputs related to all the POST arrays.

Comment: ^ and no `signup` element.

Comment: it is really length page do you want me to paste whole page in here

Comment: Not the whole page, just the full `form`.

Comment: Tell you what, visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php (set to catch and display) and also `mysqli_error($connection)` on the query as you're doing now; what does that do/show?

Comment: now have a look .. and sorry for the trouble

Comment: @chris85 undefined index deptlist all other values get inserted except for that deptlist

Comment: select belongs to a form named deptform, but I don't see any form named as such. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp

Comment: error still shows

Comment: Welcome to SO, Imtinan.  What is the error you are seeing.

Comment: thank you @TimMorton it solved the whole issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mistakenly referred to a form named deptform `<select name="deptlist" form="deptform"` but there is no such form.  This prevents the script from receiving this data.

Comment: Please don't link newbies to W3Schools. That site is considered harmful.

Comment: Removed.  Why is it considered harmful?  (I haven't paid much attention to it)

Comment: Because both their PHP and JS code is filled with vulnerabilities. And the docs regarding HTML and CSS have a tendency to be wrong and/or outdated.